# ios, ipad , MBProgressHUD works fine iphone, but not working properly in ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am using MBProgressHUD in ipad, but sometimes  it works fine, and sometimes it does not works fine(User interaction not disable even MBProgressHUD working).

On the other hand it works fine in iphone (all time).

My Code :

```
-(void)performHeavyTask {
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
[[FlrtAlertController sharedInstance]setFriendsDataDelegate:self];
[[FlrtAlertController sharedInstance] performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getDataFirstTime) withObject:nil];
```

}

Comment: Have you implemented latest version of MBProgrssHUD?

Comment: Please tell me, How do I know, whether I am using latest version of MBProgrssHUD ?

Comment: Please download latest project from this link:https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD and take a look at its readMe file. It mentions latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You should use latest version of that (v 0.9.1) with guide to install into project in link https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD/blob/master/README.mdown

And you should add MBProgressHUD to the view of NavigationController or any view of top controller in stack. See the sample project in MBProgressHUD

Comment: Hi Thanks @ iphone, Dung Nguyen, now works fine in ipad and iphone, but after made a build and when i run that build in ipad it is not working properly, works fine in iphone . Please help me, I am in trouble .